# Radio Button not showing colored text

Tags: javafx, radio-button

I have to use a Radio Button to make three Radio Buttons Red, Blue, and Green. The radio buttons are not changing to those colors. In addition to those changes, the others must stay black font. I commented out the Red setTextFill Font and there was no effect. I also commented the Black fonts and they did not do make an effect. The isSelection works.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonRadio extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // primary stage

        primaryStage.setTitle("javaFX");
        // label for text

        Label labelfirst = new Label("Choose a button");

        // vBox for buttons
        VBox layout = new VBox(3);
        // radio buttons

        RadioButton radio1, radio2, radio3;
        radio1 = new RadioButton("Red");
        radio2 = new RadioButton("Blue");
        radio3 = new RadioButton("Green");
        // ToggleGroup for entering

        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        // radio button variables of toggle groups 

        radio1.setToggleGroup(group);
        radio2.setToggleGroup(group);
        radio3.setToggleGroup(group);
        // if statements for radio buttons and fonts red, blue, green
        if (group.getSelectedToggle() != null) {

            if (radio1.isSelected()) {
                radio1.setTextFill(Color.RED); 
                radio2.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
            radio3.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

        } else if (radio2.isSelected()) {
            radio2.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
            radio1.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
            radio3.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else if (radio3.isSelected())
        {
            radio3.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
            radio1.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
            radio2.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
        }
        // layout to put in parent
        layout.getChildren().addAll(labelfirst, radio1, radio2, radio3);
        // put in scene and stage to show
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(layout, 400, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Edit:

I tried adding a listener. It still does not work.

```
                if (radio1.isSelected()) {
                radio1.setOnAction((event) -> {
                radio1.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                });
```

Comment: Looks like you need a listener.

Comment: The "listener" you added is not a listener... See my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement will only run once, checking the selected status of your `RadioButtons` only when the application first runs.

You need to listen for **changes** to the selected `RadioButton` and act accordinly. This is easily done by adding a listener to the `ToggleGroup`'s `selectedToggleProperty()`.

Remove your `if` block and replace it with something like this:

```
    group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        // Set the previously-selected RadioButton text to BLACK
        if (oldValue != null) ((RadioButton) oldValue).setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

        // Set the color for the newly-selected RadioButton
        if (newValue.equals(radio1)) {
            ((RadioButton) newValue).setTextFill(Color.RED);
        } else if (newValue.equals(radio2)) {
            ((RadioButton) newValue).setTextFill(Color.BLUE);

        } else if (newValue.equals(radio3)) {
            ((RadioButton) newValue).setTextFill(Color.GREEN);

        }

    });
```